# Sum variables generated via Instagram API

Tags: jquery, ajax, instagram

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxxxxxx",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { access_token: accessToken },
    success: function (data) {
        var followers_one = data.data.counts.followed_by;
        $('#assets .one').append(followers_one);
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxxxxxx",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { access_token: accessToken },
    success: function (data) {
        var followers_two = data.data.counts.followed_by;
        $('#assets .two').append(followers_two);
    }
});
```

I'm pulling follower counts of a few accounts with Instagram API, but now I need to sum the counts and I'm having some issues. How should I go about this considering the ajax calls?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a single function after the two ajax requests are successful using `promises` (in your case with `jQuery.when`).

From [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/):

> `jQuery.when` provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

For example:

```
$.when($.ajax( "http://example1.com" ), $.ajax( "http://example2.com" ))
    .done( function successCallback(responseFromAjax1, reponseFromAjax2) { 
        // Success code goes here ...
    });
```

In your case it will be:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxxxxxx",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { access_token: accessToken },
    }),
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxxxxxx",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { access_token: accessToken },
    })
).done(function (response1, response2) {
    // If you have troubles getting the actual data
    // put a breakpoint here to examine the structure of the responses 

    var followers_one = response1[0].data.data.counts.followed_by;
    var followers_two = response2[0].data.data.counts.followed_by;
    alert(followers_one + followers_two);
});
```